# What are alternatives to malloc() in C?

Tags: c, embedded, malloc

I am writing C for an MPC 555 board and need to figure out how to allocate dynamic memory without using malloc.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide a few more details: what kind of dynamic memory management system are you looking for? Are you looking to download something already working, or are you looking for ways of creating your own system? etc...

Comment: `malloc` is not magic, it is just the conventional name for the dynamic memory manager in c and or unix.

Comment: @dmckee: Are suggesting malloc does not manufacture memory from the elements in the vicinity of the CPU?

Comment: @GregS: Well, at least not until glibc13 is released.

Comment: @GregS: I remember in Win16/DOS times some compilers supported so called *FAR* pointers, which allowed `malloc` to manufacture memory from elements located quite far from the CPU. I wich you could see what it once did to my power supply!

Comment: @AndreyT: what happened to the power supply?

Comment: Maybe he can't use malloc because of the specialized compiler/IDE. There are many variations on C. Some people call their product C because it appears that way in convention but the syntax and library functions are sometimes different

Comment: Unless and until you explain what features you need of an allocator that malloc() does not provide, or why you cannot use malloc(), there is little likelihood of getting a useful answer other than luck that someone else's necessary assumption matches your requirements.

Answer (score 19):

<s>Typically `malloc()` is implemented on Unix using `sbrk()` or `mmap()`.  (If you use the latter, you want to use the `MAP_ANON` flag.)</s>

If you're targetting Windows, `VirtualAlloc` may help.  (More or less functionally equivalent to anonymous `mmap()`.)

**Update:** Didn't realize you weren't running under a full OS, I somehow got the impression instead that this might be a homework assignment running on top of a Unix system or something...

If you are doing embedded work and you don't have a `malloc()`, I think you should find some memory range that it's OK for you to write on, and write your own `malloc()`.  Or take someone else's.

Pretty much the standard one that everybody borrows from was written by [Doug Lea at SUNY Oswego](http://g.oswego.edu/).  For example glibc's malloc is based on this.  See: [malloc.c](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c), [malloc.h](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.h).

Comment: I get the vibe from the question that @patrick isn't using a full-fledged OS, or memory allocation would already be working for him.

Comment: In that case, you'd be looking at statically allocating a huge buffer and managing that yourself.

Comment: Good observation, Carl.  I put a <strike> around my old answer and wrote a different suggestion.

Comment: dlmalloc assumes a POSIX operating system environment, specifically, by making calls to sbrk() and mmap().  It is unclear whether the OP may utilize an sbrk() function.  The absence of malloc implies the possibility that sbrk() is disallowed.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt - It's been a while since I've looked at it, but IIRC dlmalloc has comments that say something along the lines of, "rewrite this part to provide `morecore` type functionality".  Doing this is probably simpler than writing a new malloc.

Comment: @asveikau - Doing so probably would be simpler than writing a new malloc.  There are other alternatives, such as not implementing malloc(), but rather a dynamic allocator suitable for his purpose and yet not conformant to malloc() API.  If dlmalloc were a 'drop in' solution, that would solve his problem.  Depending on his requirements, which OP hasn't fully explained, dlmalloc might be good enough.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out [Ralph Hempel's Embedded Memory Manager](https://github.com/rhempel/umm_malloc).

Answer (score 4):

If your runtime doesn't support malloc, you can find an open source malloc and tweak it to manage a chunk of memory yourself.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc()` is an abstraction that is use to allow C programs to allocate memory without having to understand details about how memory is actually allocated from the operating system.  If you can't use malloc, then you have no choice other than to use whatever facilities for memory allocation that are provided by your operating system.

If you have no operating system, then you must have full control over the layout of memory.  At that point for simple systems the easiest solution is to just make everything static and/or global, for more complex systems, you will want to reserve some portion of memory for a heap allocator and then write (or borrow) some code that use that memory to implement malloc.

Answer (score 3):

You should explain why you can't use `malloc()`, as there might be different solutions for different reasons, and there are several reasons why it might be forbidden or unavailable on small/embedded systems:

- concern over memory fragmentation.  In this case a set of routines that allocate fixed size memory blocks for one or more pools of memory might be the solution.
- the runtime doesn't provide a `malloc()` - I think most modern toolsets for embedded systems do provide some way to link in a `malloc()` implementation, but maybe you're using one that doesn't for whatever reason.  In that case, using [Doug Lea's public domain malloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) might be a good choice, but it might be too large for your system (I'm not familiar with the MPC 555 off the top of my head).  If that's the case, a very simple, custom `malloc()` facility might be in order.  It's not too hard to write, but make sure you unit test the hell out of uit because it's also easy to get details wrong.  For example, I have a set of very small routines that use a brain dead memory allocation strategy using blocks on a free list (the allocator can be compile-time configured for first, best or last fit).  I give it an array of char at initialization, and subsequent allocation calls will split free blocks as necessary. It's nowhere near as sophisticated as Lea's `malloc()`, but it's pretty dang small so for simple uses it'll do the trick.
- many embedded projects forbid the use of dynamic memory allocation - in this case, you have to live with statically allocated structures

Comment: Doug Lea's public domain malloc, used in Linux, assuems a POSIX operating system environment.  Specifically, dlmalloc makes calls to sbrk() and mmap().  It is unclear whether the OP may utilize an sbrk() function.

Comment: dlmalloc is included in newlib which runs on quite a few platforms, including at least MMU-less OS-less ARM.  It doesn't need mmap, but at least with newlib you provide your own sbrk, as in this project: https://github.com/elua/elua/blob/master/src/newlib/stubs.c  and discussed here: http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/guest-editor/4023922/Embedding-GNU-Newlib-Part-2

Answer (score 3):

An answer really depends on why you might need to dynamically allocate memory.  What is the system doing that it needs to allocate memory yet cannot use a static buffer?  The answer to that question will guide your requirements in managing memory.  From there, you can determine which data structure you want to use to manage your memory.

For example, a friend of mine wrote a thing like a video game, which rendered video in scan-lines to the screen.  That team determined that memory would be allocated for each scan-line, but there was a specific limit to how many bytes that could be for any given scene.  After rendering each scan-line, all the temporary objects allocated during that rendering were freed.

To avoid the possibility of memory leaks and for performance reasons (this was in the 90's and computers were slower then), they took the following approach:  They pre-allocated a buffer which was large enough to satisfy all the allocations for a scan-line, according to the scene parameters which determined the maximum size needed.  At the beginning of each scan-line, a global pointer was set to the beginning of the scan line.  As each object was allocated from this buffer, the global pointer value was returned, and the pointer was advanced to the next machine-word-aligned position following the allocated amount of bytes.  (This alignment padding was including in the original calculation of buffer size, and in the 90's was four bytes but should now be 16 bytes on some machinery.)  At the end of each scan-line, the global pointer was reset to the beginning of the buffer.

In "debug" builds, there were two scan buffers, which were protected using virtual memory protection during alternating scan lines.  This method detects stale pointers being used from one scan-line to the next.

The buffer of scan-line memory may be called a "pool" or "arena" depending on whome you ask.  The relevant detail is that this is a very simple data structure which manages memory for a certain task.  It is not a general memory manager (or, properly, "free store implementation") such as `malloc`, which might be what you are asking for.

Your application may require a different data structure to keep track of your free storage.  What is your application?

Answer (score 3):

Write your own.   Since your allocator will probably be specialized to a few types of objects, I recommend the [Quick Fit](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=51619&dl=GUIDE&coll=GUIDE&CFID=77829164&CFTOKEN=94987401) scheme developed by Bill Wulf and Charles Weinstock.  (I have not been able to find a free copy of this paper, but many people have access to the ACM digital library.)  The paper is short, easy to read, and well suited to your problem.

If you turn out to need a more general allocator, the best guide I have found on the topic of programming on machines with fixed memory is Donald Knuth's book [*The Art of Computer Programming*](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html), Volume 1.  If you want examples, you can find good ones in Don's epic book-length treatment of the source code of TeX, [*TeX: The Program*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201134373).

Finally, the [undergraduate textbook by Bryant and O'Hallaron](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/) is rather expensive, but it goes through the implementation of `malloc` in excruciating detail.

Comment: I am confused by the link you posted.  The code there seems to wrap malloc(), calloc() functions.

Comment: @Heath: I was the one confused.  In fact, total brain cramp.  I was thinking of something else Hanson had written that did not make it into the book.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own. Preallocate a big chunk of static RAM, then write some functions to grab and release chunks of it. That's the spirit of what `malloc()` does, except that it asks the OS to allocate and deallocate memory pages dynamically.

There are a multitude of ways of keeping track of what is allocated and what is not (bitmaps, used/free linked lists, binary trees, etc.). You should be able to find many references with a few choice Google searches.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` and its related functions are the only game in town.  You can, of course, roll your own memory management system in whatever way you choose.

Answer (score 0):

If there are issues allocating dynamic memory from the heap, you can try allocating memory from the stack using alloca(). The usual caveats apply:

- The memory is gone when you return.
- The amount of memory you can allocate is dependent on the maximum size of your stack.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in: [liballoc](http://www.smksoftware.co.za/products/liballoc/)

It's a simple, easy-to-implement malloc/free/calloc/realloc replacement which works.

If you know beforehand or can figure out the available memory regions on your device, you can also use their libbmmm to manage these large memory blocks and provide a backing-store for liballoc. They are BSD licensed and free.

Comment: liballoc states that it requires a "standard UNIX environment" which it seems the OP does not have.  I imagine liballoc calls sbrk() and mmap().

Comment: liballoc doesn't require much. It requires a way to allocate pages of memory(*very* trivial to implement a page manager). mmap and sbrk has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

FreeRTOS contains 3 examples implementations of memory allocation (including `malloc()`) to achieve different optimizations and use cases appropriate for small embedded systems (AVR, ARM, etc).  See the [FreeRTOS manual](http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html) for more information.

I don't see a port for the MPC555, but it shouldn't be difficult to adapt the code to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If the library supplied with your compiler does not provide malloc, then it probably has no concept of a heap.

A heap (at least in an OS-less system) is simply an area of memory reserved for dynamic memory allocation.  You can reserve such an area simply by creating a suitably sized statically allocated array and then providing an interface to provide contiguous chunks of this array on demand and to manage chunks in use and returned to the heap.

A somewhat neater method is to have the linker allocate the heap from whatever memory remains after stack and static memory allocation.  That way the heap is always automatically as large as it possibly can be, allowing you to use all available memory simply.  This will require modification of the application's linker script.  Linker scripts are specific to the particular toolchain, and invariable somewhat arcane.

K&R included a simple implementation of malloc for example.